# Defaults tool equivalent of Ctrl-F7

Tags: macos, ui, defaults

In OSX one can use Ctrl-F7 to change what the Tab key can move the focus between. By default it is only text boxes and lists but after pressing ctrl-f7 one can move between all ui elements.

I was wondering if there is a way to toggle this functionality by using the `defaults` tool.

Comment: Are you aware that you can change this setting in Preferences/Keyboard as well?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know if there is a way to modify this preference using the defaults tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching the equivalent command using the `defaults` tool is

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 2
```

Anyone can verify this by toggling the values and then reading the key value. The default value has a value of 0 and switching it to all ui elements will turn it to a value of 2.